# Typo3 PDF indexing Index Search

Tags: indexing, typo3

I have typo3 site with more than 2000 pdfs
I wanted to index only the pdf names or only the first page of a PDF.

Currently it indexes entire PDF and its taking lot of time to index entire website.
and some time server get crashes.

Is there any way to index only the pdf names or First page of pdf.

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of configuration options in the Extension Manager:

- You can empty the path to the PDF parser to disable PDF parsing.
- You can limit the number of pages indexed at once to 1 (see detailed description in extension manager).
- You can define how many files are indexed at a time at maximum (default: 5)
- You could indexed_search let put the external files only to the queue without indexing them. Then you can use the "crawler" extension to do that task in the background.

(Source: https://git.typo3.org/Packages/TYPO3.CMS.git/blob/HEAD:/typo3/sysext/indexed_search/ext_conf_template.txt)

Comment: Thank you for the Quick reply.
If i set pdf_mode = 1 then whole page will index in one file.
But i want to index only one page pdf not the whole pdf.
Because of lot of pdfs in my site .